# How can I group several rows from my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I want to group all pharmacies present in the same night in a unique row following this night.

```
select days.day, pharmacy.name
from days,
     pharmacy,
     pharmacy_night
where (pharmacy.Id_pharmacy in (SELECT Id_pharmacy
                                FROM pharmacy_in_region(@idregion))
  and pharmacy.Id_pharmacy = pharmacy_night.Id_pharmacy
  and days.Id_day = pharmacy_night.Id_day)
```

The desired output:

```
row 1: Monday  Pharmacy1_pahrmacy5-
row 2: Tuesday pharmacy9_
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Probably product specific functionality will be used.)

Comment: so fo each monday one location

Answer (score 0):

Re-wrote with modern explicit `JOIN` syntax. I guess you want something like MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT`, or similar product specific function. (No dbms specified...)

```
select days.day, GROUP_CONCAT(pharmacy.name)
from days
  join pharmacy_night on days.Id_day = pharmacy_night.Id_day
  join pharmacy on pharmacy.Id_pharmacy = pharmacy_night.Id_pharmacy
where pharmacy.Id_pharmacy in (SELECT Id_pharmacy
                               FROM pharmacy_in_region(@idregion))
group by days.day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT days.day
     , (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + pharmacy.name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM pharmacy 
         WHERE (pharmacy.Id_pharmacy in (SELECT Id_pharmacy
                                FROM pharmacy_in_region(@idregion))
  and pharmacy.Id_pharmacy = pharmacy_night.Id_pharmacy
  and days.Id_day = pharmacy_night.Id_day)
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS Locations
FROM days,
     pharmacy_night
```

try stuff + xml path if it is sql server

Comment: what  about this error:The object reference [dbo].[Pharmacy] differs only by case from the object definition [dbo].[pharmacy].

Comment: @GhadirAyache try the edited one..i put the table name pharmacy again at last `From` class..now i removed..i didnt tested this code..try and tell me

Comment: @GhadirAyache check the error buddy..one Pharmacy has upper case P and second has small one..try to change it in code and check the result

Comment: @GhadirAyache what u got?